# Typescript custom restriction with Generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

While working on a library, I discovered what to me looks like a bug when using Generics:

```
type R<A> = A extends Bottom ? A : A
type Bottom = { test: number }

const f = <A extends Bottom>(a: A) => {
    useIt(a) // type error here
}

const useIt = <A extends Bottom>(a: R<A>) => console.log(a)
```

As you can also see in the 
[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=60#code/C4TwDgpgBASgPAQQHxQLxQVCAPYEB2AJgM5QBCA9sMBQLZQD8GUAXBgFCiTlU33oBvKHmLA2+AK60ARhABOUAL7t2AYwr5RUAGZooiLLgIke1OkgAUAQzYIAlGhQD2UV1AnEIASWDW77ZTUNLQ9vYD0DHDwiUkozWksbWEQkB1QUdU0KABsIADpsigBzPyA), for some unclear reason `a` cannot be used as `R<A>`, even though this type is equivalent to `A`.

The type error is:

```
Argument of type 'A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'R<A>'.
  Type 'Bottom' is not assignable to type 'R<A>'.
```

Using a concrete type instead of a generic will work as expected, eg:

```
type X = {test: 1}
const x: R<X> = {test: 1} // all good
const noX: R<X> = {test: 2} // error
```

Having a better restriction type will also work as expected for concrete types:

```
type R<A> = A extends Bottom ? A : never
const x: R<X> = {test: 1} // all good
const error: R<{}> = {} // type error as expected given that {} doesn't extend Bottom
```

So, is there any way to make it work with Generics?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a design limitation than a bug; unresolved conditional types (ones which depend on a yet-to-be-specified generic type parameter) are more or less deferred completely by the compiler, and almost nothing is seen as assignable to them.

---

There's an open issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#23132](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23132), that suggests using generic constraints to determine assignability to unresolved conditional types; I think if this suggestion were implemented your example code would work (because `A extends Bottom` would be seen as true)... so you might want to go that issue and give it a  and possibly explain your use case if you think it's more compelling than what's there.

There's also [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), which proposes using control flow analysis to determine assignability to unresolved conditional types, which might also help if it were to be implemented.

---

Right now I think the only way to "make it work" is either to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), as in:

```
useIt(a as R<A>)
```

or to express your type so that it is no longer an unresolved conditional type, if possible; in your example code, `R<A>` is unconditionally `A`, so

```
// type R<A> = A extends Bottom ? A : A
type R<A> = A
```

would solve it.

Actually I see you changed `R<A>` in another part of your code to be essentially `Extract<A, Bottom>`.  In some instances, `Extract<T, U>` can be replaced by the intersection `T & U` without ill effects; you might try that instead:

```
// type R<A> = A extends Bottom ? A : never
type R<A> = A & Bottom
```

That might also work.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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)

Comment: Thank you a lot for all the info! My actual use case is a lot more complex. I'm trying to implement some flexible constraint for a UI library. Have a look at : https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23132#issuecomment-545642342

Comment: In the end I solved the problem by adding the restriction to the other function too, see my answer for more details

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tinkering, I solved this problem by explicitly adding the restriction:

```
const f = <A extends Bottom>(a: R<A>) => {
    useIt(a) // works
}

const useIt = <A extends Bottom>(a: R<A>) => console.log(a)
```

Please note that now `f` argument has the same constraint of `useIt`, which will make the compiler happy. With hindsight, this actually makes sense, so that we are 100% sure the type is usable for `useIt` too :)