# TypeScript conditional types with generics and objects

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
type Id = string | number;

type ObjectId<T extends Id> = {
  id: T;
};

type ValidObjectId = ObjectId<string> | ObjectId<number>

type ReverseId<T extends ValidObjectId> = T['id'] extends number ? string : number;

function encodeObjectId<T extends ObjectId<number>>(
  obj: T
): ReverseId<T> {
  const id = obj.id;

  // Why does the following does not accept a string type?
  // As it's the reverse of type number, because of the `ReverseId` type, it should be working.
  return id.toString();
}
```

<sup>[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJlAvFAzsATgSwHYHMoA+U2ArgLYBGE6A3ALABQjokUA8hQFYQDGw8AHgAqUCAA9gEbHBSw4APiRQA3oyhRMcAFxQh9BgF99zcNABqAQwA2mjtz7wld3vzgC0WPIqLOHb0pTU8owmrABKEABu1CgQgiLiktKyljZwvq6KyEIA2gDkmnkAuqISUjLE5FToUAD8qBg4+DoB1cYMAGYk2HyYAPbYoj19cBAZ8aVJFeP+VUHyABRqUH1cOkKMAJQ6EdHosfGKqgzqPANoGgjIq5wAdJrt6gD0T1AA6gAWIFBwfRCywA+0A6fSsVj6AHcmj8-rJsH1gFALDweBAwIiLA1PPgWBBassXlAAIKyTDAPIAoFQdBRGLQPodKC4yqBdAAGigVB4FhIsRWjMB0AABrs6fAhUzTByyagPn0SFYEFQoBC+ugANZNW7LGnAEjoQaaW7APoAZUaeAWm30BiAA)</sup>

In it, I have the type `ReverseId`, which converts the type of the `id` property. For example, if the given object `id` property has a `number` type, it will return `string`; and if the  given object's `id` property has a `string` type, the `number` type will be returned.

And that actually works:

```
type Id = string | number;

type ObjectId<T extends Id> = {
  id: T;
};

type ValidObjectId = ObjectId<string> | ObjectId<number>

type ReverseId<T extends ValidObjectId> = T['id'] extends number ? string : number;

// The `t` constant has a `number` type, which is the "reverse" of the `string`
// type, used in the given `ObjectId`.
const t: ReverseId<ObjectId<string>> = 1;
```

<sup>[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJlAvFAzsATgSwHYHMoA+U2ArgLYBGE6A3ALABQjokUA8hQFYQDGw8AHgAqUCAA9gEbHBSw4APiRQA3oyhRMcAFxQh9BgF99zcNABqAQwA2mjtz7wld3vzgC0WPIqLOHb0pTU8owmrABKEABu1CgQgiLiktKyljZwvq6KyEIA2gDkmnkAuqISUjLE5FToUAD8qBg4+DoB1cYMAPQdugAW0AAGwP1QPAD22GgW2MBQPRayFlD9rdTDLBAANFAA7j2YPD0assB9UABE6FExEGdQowBmUCcDHk39jF1PplsksQg4T1OuEw0WwSwy8H6ADpGGMJjNgDoItF0LFBBC3K8vFkoABGGhAA)</sup>

The problem is: when the `ObjectId` comes from a generic, as we saw in the `encodeObjectId` function in the first example, the type does not work.

Is there a way to solve this problem using conditional types?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript custom restriction with Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58521104/typescript-custom-restriction-with-generics)

Comment: The issue is the same as in the linked question: unresolved conditional types are essentially opaque and the compiler doesn't see anything as assignable to them.  There is [a suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23132) that, if implemented, would maybe solve the problem, but until then you either need to use type assertions (or the equivalent, like overload signatures) or refactor away from conditional types.

Comment: Here's a non-conditional `ReverseId` which happens to work but I wouldn't use it in any prod environment: `type ReverseId<T extends ValidObjectId> = ({ [k: string]: number } & { [k: number]: string })[T["id"]];`